# Error "unique table/alias" when joining 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to print items from table *items* by the Id_item found in the table *favorites_items*. I'm using the Codeigniter framework.

the error:

> Not unique table/alias: 'favorites_items'
>
> SELECT favorites_items.*, items.* FROM favorites_items JOIN
>   favorites_items ON id_item = items.id_ad

Code:

```
$this->db->select('favorites_items.*,items.*');
$this->db->from('favorites_items');
$this->db->join('favorites_items', 'id_item = items.id_ad');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: what is your tables structure? why do you try  join `favorites_items` with `favorites_items`? btw, this helped me a lot to understand joins: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: I want to print items from items according to the id in favorites_items
I have tried to remove ways but show me this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't join the table *items*, you join the table *favorites_items* to the table *favorites_items*

the correct way would be like:

```
$this->db->select('favorites_items.*,items.*');
$this->db->from('favorites_items');
$this->db->join('items', 'favorites_items.id_item = items.id_ad');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```